# Bootstrap collapse will open but not close

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Here is a link to the front end. [Collapse not closing](https://this-should-work-trimakas.c9.io/merchants/4)

I have it in a Datatables table.. and just using bootstrap classes to open and close everything.. Here is my code:

```
<%= form_tag push_to_shopify_products_path, :id => 'submit_to_shopify' do  %>
  <table id="products" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered 
  table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> </th>        
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="select-all" id="select-all" /></th>
      <th><a>TITLE</a></th>
      <th><a>ASIN</a></th>
      <th><a>PRICE</a></th>
      <th><a>SKU</a></th>
      <th> </th>
      <th> </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="product-index">

    <% @merchant.products.each do |product| %>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" 
          data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<%= product.asin %>" 
          aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
          Button
          </button>
            <div class="collapse" id="<%= product.asin %>">
            <div>
            Why won't this do anything other than open then close?
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td><%= check_box_tag('sellersku[]', product.sellersku) %></td>
        <td><%= product.title %></td>
        ...
      </tr>

    <% end %>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: The URL to your page is returning a Rails error. Does the browser console give you any errors when you load the page?

Comment: No nothing.. I'll get a fiddle going because the link isn't working